# No syntax error is thrown for a non-existent object field

Tags: javascript

I am a total newbie to Javascript. While reading about the concept of [immutability](https://itnext.io/why-concept-of-immutability-is-so-damn-important-for-a-beginner-front-end-developer-8da85b565c8e) in JS, I came across this code snipt :

```
var obj = {field: 'value'};
function changeObject(input){
    input.someOtherField = 'some other value';
}
changeObject(obj);
console.log(obj.someOtherField); //prints 'some other value'
console.log(obj.field);//prints 'value'
```

I could not figure out how the so called field `someOtherField` in `obj` came to existence! Normally the interpreter should throw a syntax error but it didn't. Could someone explain me please why?

Comment: Why would it throw an error? You created the property with `input.someOtherField = 'some other value'`

Comment: Would not this mislead the developer if he ever misspells the name of the field? Let's say the object has one and one field only like the code snipt above, let's call it 'field'. The developer however made a typo while trying to mutate the value of the field 'field' and he typed instead 'fiield'. When reading later on the value of 'field' he would not get the updated value and the interpreter would not throw a syntax error  either. I just don't see the point of having such a feature in JS. Do you have any thoughts on the please.

Comment: If you're worried about being able to misspell properties and cause bugs, I'd use Typescript instead

Comment: CertainPerformance Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could not figure out how the so called field someOtherField in obj came to existence!

Because that's how JavaScript is defined. You don't have to declare properties in advance *(although you* can*, now, in `class` constructs)*, you can create them via assignment.

Some languages are more rigid, you have to tell them the shape of the object in advance. JavaScript is not.

> Normally the interpreter should throw a syntax error but it didn't.

Not in JavaScript. There is no syntax error in your code. (Even in languages with more rigid structures, I wouldn't expect it to be a *syntax* error. An error, yes, but not a syntax error.)

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Would not this mislead the developer if he ever misspells the name of the field?

Yes, this is something that's been a problem on occasion. It's usually addressed by some kind of linting or pre-processing stage. The most popular one at the moment is [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/): It overlays a strict type system on top of JavaScript and raises errors for exactly the kind of situations you describe. It's a very smart and flexible language. If you want strict typing for JavaScript, it's what I'd use. (In fact, it's what I *do* use, in situations where I want strict typing.) (TypeScript isn't the only game in town, though, there's also [Flow](https://flow.org/en/). I haven't used it.)